# How to convert multiple INNER JOINs into a generic/programmable function

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join, plpgsql

Let's say we store files and their attributes (Several different attributes exist and each attribute has a value):

```sql
CREATE TABLE file(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT file_primarykey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE attribute(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT attribute_primarykey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE file_attribute(
    id UUID NOT NULL,
    file_id UUID NOT NULL,
    attribute_id UUID NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT file_attribute_primarykey PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT file_attribute_foreignkey_file_id FOREIGN KEY(file_id) REFERENCES file ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT file_attribute_foreignkey_attribute_id FOREIGN KEY(attribute_id) REFERENCES attribute ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO file(id, name) VALUES
('aaa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'Die Verwandlung.pdf'),
('bba2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'Star Wars.pdf');

INSERT INTO attribute(id, name) VALUES
('11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'FILE_SIZE'),
('1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'FILE_EXTENSION'),
('2aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'FILE_OWNER');

INSERT INTO file_attribute(id, file_id, attribute_id, value) VALUES
('1111a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'aaa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '101'),
('2222a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'aaa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '.pdf'),
('3333a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'aaa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '2aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'James'),
('4444a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'bba2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '251'),
('5555a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', 'bba2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da', '.pdf');
```

The situation: I want to fetch files by their attribute(s):

```sql
-- Search for all files that have a file attribute "FILE_EXTENSION" ending with .pdf --> Will return Die Verwandlung
SELECT f.id, f.name FROM file f INNER JOIN file_attribute fa ON f.id = fa.file_id WHERE fa.attribute_id = '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa.value = '.pdf';

-- Search for all files that have a file attribute "FILE_SIZE" with the size of 251 -->  Will return Star Wars
SELECT f.id, f.name FROM file f INNER JOIN file_attribute fa ON f.id = fa.file_id WHERE fa.attribute_id = '11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa.value = '251';

-- Search for file extension .pdf and file size 101 --> Will return Die Verwandlung
SELECT f.id, f.name FROM file f
INNER JOIN file_attribute fa1 ON f.id = fa1.file_id
INNER JOIN file_attribute fa2 ON f.id = fa2.file_id 
WHERE fa1.attribute_id = '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa1.value = '.pdf' AND fa2.attribute_id = '11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa2.value = '101';
```

Question/Problem:

1.) How dow multiple joins influence the performance [on the same joined table]? Any tips for [premature] optimization? Or is there a better way to design the query?

2.) How can I transform the query into a custom function so I can pass down the attribute_ids's and value's in a map-style way? The idea is to search files for 0 - n file attributes + additional columns in file that are not part of this question. Pseudo call:

```sql
select search_files([{attribute_id: 1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da, value: .pdf}, {attribute_id: 11a2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da, value: 101}])
```

I want to call this function from `JDBC` and want to pass down the values as `Map` (If somehow possible)

Answer (score 0):

Exists in the where clause is likely better if you don't need the attributes in the resulting rs

There is no issue with adding this in a function?

```
SELECT f.id, f.name FROM file f 
WHERE EXISTS (select 0 from file_attribute fa1 ON f.id = fa1.file_id and fa1.attribute_id = '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa1.value = '.pdf') AND 
EXISTS (select 0 from file_attribute fa2 ON f.id = fa2.file_id and fa2.attribute_id = '1aa2a8e9-a004-44bf-9ec7-0c20733380da' AND fa2.value = '101')
```